# grab lines form file in python

Tags: python

i am trying to grab some lines form lines in a huge file. For example suppose 
f =

```
a b
c d
e s
m n
h g
.
.
.
```

The code  I am trying to used is as follows

```
import re
f = open('f.txt')
y = [a,s, ...] # the laters that i would like to grab it with the line form the file f
grab = y
for line in f:
    match = grab.search(line)
    if match: 
        print match.group()
```

Comment: what do you want to do with your data ? what is going wrong ?

Comment: You should go back and accept answers to some of your old questions. You should also upvote the answers that helped you (like the one you accepted here) -- that's what makes Stack Overflow work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code you will print lines from `f` if any of the chars in `y` is in the line.
You can modify it easily if what you want is to get lines where both chars are in `y`

```
for line in f:
    letters = line.split()
    for letter in letters:
       if letter in y:
           print line
           break
```

btw, do not forget to close your open file or better to use `with as` .